# Airflow : Publish a dynamically created dag

Tags: airflow

I want to be able to publish and trigger a DAG object from my code which is not in control of scheduler (viz. **$AIRFLOW_HOME/dags** folder)

My last resort would be to programmatically create a py file containing the DAG definition that I want to publish and save this file to the **$AIRFLOW_HOME/dags** folder.
I'm sure it should be easier than that.

Below is what I've tried.

```
import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import timedelta

from airflow.models import DagPickle
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.utils.db import provide_session


@provide_session
def submit_dag(session=None):
    args = {
        'owner': 'airflow',
        'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(2)
    }

    dag = DAG(
        dag_id='sample', default_args=args,
        schedule_interval=None, start_date=airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(2),
        dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=60))
    task = DummyOperator(task_id='one', dag=dag)
    dag_pickle = DagPickle(task)
    session.add(dag_pickle)
    session.commit()


submit_dag()
```

The above code does create entries in **dag_pickle** table but how do I publish and later trigger this dag?

Comment: Airflow designed to deal with DAGs that defined in python file in `$AIRFLOW_HOME/dags` folder. Python script can dynamically define a DAG (based on whatever you'd like, data in a file, in SQL database, etc) The limitation is execution time if I remember right the default timeout about 10-20 sec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can do pickle.dump(dag,open(DAGS_FOLDER/pickled_dags,'wb')) and have a file in DAGS FOLDER that would pickle.load(DAGS_FOLDER/pickled_dags)

Comment: wouldnt it be enough to just persist to the DAGS_FOLDER? Not sure why you would need the pickle.load again manually?